# Showing the convergence of the product for $ (1-\frac{1}{k})$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

What I am trying to calculate is the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left( 1-\frac{1}{k}\right).$$

I know that it approaches 0 as n approaches infinity, the problem I have is actually showing it. So far, I tried to express it as

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k-1}{k}$$

hoping that this would simplify the problem, but it didn't help too much. Likewise, proving that it is monotonically increasing didn't either, in fact it made me doubt that it converges towards 0 for a bit. I tried around a few more possible solutions, but most of them are garbage that isn't worth the time to write down here, so I'd be thankful for any nudge into the right direction as to how to solve this.

Comment: You should try to write your product explicitly, you will see most terms will be cancelled.

Comment: Is it the sum or the product? Your title mentions the sum but your question is actually about product.

Comment: It's the product, sorry. My mind was on "sum" when I wrote the title, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (n-1)}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot \cdots \cdot n}=\frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: That just made it click for me. Thank you.